# conditional erb not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a dropdown menu with a link to the user's profile page (`UserProfile`). The `user.user_profile` is not created by default, so the link should only show if an associated user profile is present.

I currently have:

```
<% if profile_present? %>
 <%= link_to "My profile", user_profile_path(current_user.user_profile) %>
<% end %>
```

My helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def profile_present?
    current_user.user_profile.present? if user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

The goal is to only execute the code if the condition is met.

Any suggestions?

When the user profile is not present, this trows me a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError`.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The application trace:

```
app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb:44:in `_app_views_layouts__navbar_html_erb___2344119771953232299_47030678815860'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:27:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1177681419623347300_69843401266740'
```

`
**UPDATE:**

rake routes:

```
                   user_profiles GET      /user_profiles(.:format)                user_profiles#index
                                 POST     /user_profiles(.:format)                user_profiles#create
                new_user_profile GET      /user_profiles/new(.:format)            user_profiles#new
               edit_user_profile GET      /user_profiles/:id/edit(.:format)       user_profiles#edit
                    user_profile GET      /user_profiles/:id(.:format)            user_profiles#show
                                 PATCH    /user_profiles/:id(.:format)            user_profiles#update
                                 PUT      /user_profiles/:id(.:format)            user_profiles#update
                                 DELETE   /user_profiles/:id(.:format)            user_profiles#destroy
```

Comment: This might be something simple, but it's hard to tell unless you post your `profile_present?` method.

Comment: the error is probably in your `profile_present?` condition. Can you provide more info about the error too?

Comment: Could you share your code for `profile_present` as well as getting the current user? Odds are, it's passing `nil` to the `user_profile_path` and throwing an error.

Comment: Why not `user.user_profile.present?` ?

Comment: show the helper `profile_present?` method also

Comment: I just exchanged my helper `profile_present?` for `current_user.user_profile.present?` which is supposed to do the same thing. It still gives me this error...

Comment: Can you show us some stacktrace of the error you get?

Comment: Also, can you run `rake routes`? Maybe it's a routing issue.

Comment: See update. It seems that user.user_profile is nil, which makes sense if it does not exist. But, this line should be executed at all in my view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the fix, it is advisable to remove the conditional from your view and into a helper method..

```
Module ApplicationHelper
  def user_profile_link
    if current_user.user_profile?
      link_to 'My profile', user_profile_path(current_user.user_profile)
    end
  end
end
```

**ERB:**

```
<%= user_profile_link %>
```

Comment: @Matthias have updated my answer. It is likely because you are not passing in the correct arguments to the route helper. What is the output of `rake routes`? It should be either `...path(current_user)` or `...path(current_user, current_user.user_profile)`

Comment: See my updated post. I'm assuming it requires the `current_user.user_profile.id`. If a `current_user.user_profile` does not exist the id passed in to the helper is `nil`. What I don't understand is WHY this syntax is executed even when `user_profile?` is false....

Comment: @Matthias it might be worth jumping into `rails console` and executing these methods directly until you understand how they work. You should only have to pass in `current_user.user_profile` and that check should return false (`current_user.user_profile?`) if it is nil.

Answer (score 0):

**This may solve your problem**

if you have a column user_profile in user table and its data_type is Boolean then you can use:

```
if current_user.user_profile?
```

directly  there is not necessary to create a separate method in helper.
If there no profile present set value of user_profile false and when user creates profile set user_profile to 1 or true.